# fill every empty cell after a range of datas in the same column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to vba and I'm struggling with this little problem.
I haven't found any posts dealing with this issue though.

here is the point:

I'd like to fill every cell of a board bellow a range of datas with a specific value.
Let's say I've already got  a range of datas in the column A ,  I'd like, in the same column, the line after the last cell filled with "a" values ( that can vary) fill  the next empty cells with a specific value ( "b").

Here is an example of what I'd like to do as a final result;

| column A |
| --- |
| a |
| a |
| a |
| a |
| a |
| a |
| b |
| b |
| b |
| b |
| b |

I tried to code it but as soon as I launched it nothing happens, nothing changes.
Here it is ;

```
Sub test()

Dim firstlineb As Long
Dim lastlineEmpty As Long
Dim x As Integer

firstlineb = Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("A2",Range("A2").End(xlDown)).End(xlDown).Offset(1)
lastlineEmpty = Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("A2",Range("A2").End(xlDown)).End(xlDown).Offset(1).End(xlDown)

For x = firstlineb To lastlineEmpty
    
    Cells(x, 1).Value = "b"
    
    
Next x
 
End Sub
```

I'd heavily appreciate your help. Thank you a lot !

Comment: As this is related to VBA and SO is not a code-for-you service, but a collaborative site for aiding in your specific coding issue, **what have you tried thusfar**?  Please update your post to include your existing code.

Comment: Hello Cyril. Sorry I forgot to put it. Here You can find up above my post refreshed with my code .

Comment: "Nothing happens" doesn't tell much.  Did it compile, did you attempt to step through (F8) to see where there was an issue?

Comment: Are you trying to fill all 1M+ lines with value `b`?  What dictates how many rows `b` will be filled into?  I will try to give a mock-up of something in the Answer section, as it will be easier to read code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your problem correctly but try this :

```
Sub test()

Dim firstlineb As Range
Dim lastlineEmpty As Range
Dim cel As Range

Set firstlineb = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
Set lastlineEmpty = Range(firstlineb, firstlineb.End(xlDown))

For Each cel In lastlineEmpty.Cells
    If cel = "" Then
        cel.Value = "b"
    Else: Exit Sub
    End If
Next cel
 
End Sub
```

I think you got lost with the ".End(xlDown)", if you set up the variable as a range you can then use it like a cell :

```
Range(firstlineb, firstlineb.End(xlDown))
```

This way you won't have those repetition :

```
Range("A2",Range("A2").End(xlDown)).End(xlDown).Offset(1).End(xlDown)
```

Note : I tried the vba on the sheet directly and not in a module, so you'll have to add "Worsheets("Sheet1")" before the range.

I hope that it helped you a bit.

Comment: Hello Wadax, that was exactly what I wanted  !

Comment: I've got an other request about an other code issue. ShouldI open an other post? It follows this one however...

Comment: Open another one and link this at the beginning of your post I guess.

Answer (score 0):

We'll make a couple assumptions:

- `Columns(1)` has the values you want to assess, `a`
- `Columns(2)` has labels so you can find your last row for end of all data entry, so you know where `Columns(1)` data needs to extend, `b`

We want to find the last row of each (untested with explanatory comments):

```
With Sheets(1)
    dim lastValueRow as Long
    lastValueRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row 'Columns(1) = Columns("A")
    dim lastDescriptionRow as Long
    lastDescriptionRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row 'Columns(2) = Columns("B")
    'Using the above, you can paste a single value over a range, without needing to loop
    .Range(.Cells(lastValueRow+1, 1),.Cells(lastDescriptionRow, 1)).Value = "b"
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Cyril! It helped me for an other problem I got with an other sheet haha.